# Preventing object comparision in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way in JS to prevent object comparision?

Lets say i have:

```
function Person(data) {
  var that = {};
  that.name = data.name;
  return that;
}

let p = new Person({'name':'John'})
```

Now i want this to throw an error:

`p == 2`

Comment: I don't think so. What would be the added benefit or use case?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: Do you want to throw exceptions only when comparing against numbers, or when comparing against anything?

Comment: @Bergi When comparing to anything.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier use case is preventing other users of code base of making a mistake, since my example would always return false.

Comment: @VladimirGromes That's not possible. Also I doubt that you really *want* `p == p` to throw an exception instead of returning `true`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is by relying on the fact that the comparison operator (`==`) uses string conversion to compare operands of different types:

```js
function Person(data) {
  var that = {};
  that.name = data.name;
  return that;
}

let p = new Person({'name':'John'});

p.toString = function() {
  throw 'Error!';
}

p == 2
```

Of course, that would cause errors for all other string conversion of said object too, and it wouldn't work for the strict comparison operator (`===`).